# Apache Wink and Apache CXF JAX-RS Implementation

Tags: java, apache, rest, cxf, jax-rs

Why are there two implementations of JAX-RS by Apache?

CXF seems to be a huge bundle including jax-ws and jax-rs. Wink seems to be more lightweight. So which one is better to use? Has someone experience with one or both implementations? Maybe one of them is already outdated?

I know that there are other implementations for jax-rs, but I want to get information just about these two.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With CXF 2.6.x, you can use the smaller jars/bundles that wouldn't pull in the jaxws stuff if you don't need it.   Still likely larger than Wink though.

For the most part, CXF has a much more vibrant community behind it with ongoing development, enhancements, etc... Wink has been pretty much dead, with very little activity at all.   If you need some advanced stuff, CXF is definitely the better option.   Things like OAuth/OAuth2, SAML, advanced encryption/security, various transformation things, extra type options, etc....   All areas that are actively supported and enhanced in CXF.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Wink is [officially retired as of April 2017](https://wink.apache.org/).

> **2017/04/25 - Apache Wink has been retired.**
>   For more information, please explore the [**Attic**](http://attic.apache.org/).